# How does chrome os use Chrome as a user interface

Tags: mobile, browser, operating-system

I have been thinking of how does chrome os creates its user interface with chrome browser

I have searched I have not gotten a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Chrome OS is a Linux-based operating system designed by Google. It is derived from the free software Chromium OS and uses the Google Chrome Web browser as its principle user interface.Because Chrome OS use a web browser engine for the user interface, they are oriented towards web application rather than desktop applications or mobile apps.
Here browser engine is a core software component of every major web browser. The primary job of a browser engine is to transform HTML documents and other resources of a web page into a interactive visual representation on a user's device.

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't get it, how is a browser engine the primary UI of the os??